# How to get synthesized disk root device from shell?

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, apfs

I have quite a few volumes (over 10) on a machine and I need to ascertain the parent volume of synthesized volumes for APFS drives.

If you execute `diskutil list` you get a list of volumes, but this list includes both root volumes and synthesized volumes, for example:

```
...
/dev/disk11 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk11
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk11s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk16        2.0 TB     disk11s2

/dev/disk12 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk12
   1:                        ZFS backup_tank             4.0 TB     disk12s1
   2: 6423532B-1232-1121-1532-062424236333               67.1 MB    disk12s9

/dev/disk13 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk13
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume users_drive             1.2 TB     disk13s1

/dev/disk14 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +XX.X TB    disk14
   1:                ZFS Dataset storage                 XX.X TB    disk14s1

/dev/disk15 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk15
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk15s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk10        499.2 GB   disk15s2
   3:       Apple_KernelCoreDump                         655.4 MB   disk15s3

/dev/disk16 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk16
                                 Physical Store disk11s2
   1:                APFS Volume system_2                847.9 KB   disk16s1
```

Notice how in the above it is difficult to ascertain which volume the synthesized volume `disk16` actually belongs to.

Is there a way to get this information from the shell quickly so that it lists these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the apfs verb with diskutil:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

This produces a ‘graphical’ output of the APFS hierarchy, matching container partitions to their container contents.